# Php - Полигон из линий

Tags: php, gis, геометрия

Помогите, не могу придумать алгоритм. Есть набор линий с точками L1[P1, P2]; L2[P2, P3]; L3[P3, P4]; L4[P4, P1] 
Если тупо все слить в один массив то получается дубликаты точек конца и начала линии. Если проверять дубликаты то вылетают первая и последняя точки. Полигон получается не замкнутый.

Comment: А что надо получить-то в итоге? "Набор линий с точками" - это уже массив, зачем с ним что-то ещё делать?

Comment: В итоге получить полигон с точками

Comment: array(
    'L1' => array('P1','P2'),
    'L2' => array('P2','P3'),
    'L3' => array('P3','P4'),
    'L4' => array('P4','P1')
)

Comment: Всё равно непонятно в чём проблема. С удалением дубликатов в массиве оказываются (P1,P2,P3,P4) - полный набор, ничего не вылетает.

Comment: Полигон получается не закрытый должно быть (P1,P2,P3,P4,P1)

Comment: Ну добавьте первую точку в конце, делов-то. Правда, непонятно зачем: полигон прекрасно описывается количеством точек, равным количеству вершин.